# Nth derivative differentiation

Tags: derivatives

The question is the nth derivative of $x^{x}$

I have try solving this nth term differentiation of x raised to the power of x. Using $y=x^{x}$ and taking he log of both sides...but I don't know how to differentiate the nth term. Pls help

Comment: Hint: $x^x = \mathrm{e}^{x \ln x}$.

Comment: Have you tried computing a few derivatives? What did you get when you logged both sides and tried differentiating? It helps if you actually write out what you've tried. And is there any reason you expect a closed form?